# Help Solve Recurrence Relation T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(n)

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Given recurrence $$T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(n)$$
$$let\:cn >= O(n)$$ for some constant c I can bound $$T(n)$$ in terms of $$T(n/2)$$

so I have $$T(n) <= 3T(n/2)+cn, \ \ \ \ \  k = 1 \ call$$

So I expanded the recurrence a few times and got

$$T(n) <= 9T(n/4)+2cn, \ \ \ \ \  k = 2  \ calls$$
$$T(n) <= 27T(n/8)+3cn, \ \ \ \ \  k = 3  \ calls$$

The emerged pattern is

$$T(n) <= 3^kT(n/2^k)+kcn, \ \ \ \ \  k^{th} \ call$$

---

Solving for k: $n/2^k = 1$

$ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ I have  k = $\log_2 n$

Im not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Note that there's one problem with the written solution here - you're adding $cn$ as though it were a constant on each level, but in fact as you 'expand out' the recurrence $n$ is changing each time so the trailing term has to change. (Fortunately this doesn't impact the final result, but it's worth calling out; in fact, the linear term is bounded by $2cn$ at any level $k$.)

Answer (score 3):

Is this from CLRS book?

In my opinion, the best way to solve this is by using the recursion tree method. You can see that the pattern is:

$ \frac{n}{2^i} = 1 \\
i = lg(n) \\
 $

Then the tree has $ lg(n) $ levels.

The tree has $ 3^i $ nodes at the last level, which give us the cost:
$ 3^i = 3^{lg(n)} = n^{lg(3)} $

Now we have to calculate the cost for each node! Since we know that each level has a linear cost form ($ \theta(n) $), we can multiply this cost by the number of nodes at each $i^{th}$ level:

$ 3^ic(\frac{n}{2^i}) = nc(\frac{3}{2})^i $

Great! The only thing left is to sum this cost for all levels, including the last level, for which we know that the cost is $n^{lg(3)}$:

$ T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{lgn - 1} nc(\frac{3}{2})^i + \theta(n^{lg3}) $

$ \quad\quad = nc \sum_{i=0}^{lg n - 1} (\frac{3}{2})^i + \theta(n^{lg3}) $

Clearly, this is a geometric series. Then, we can use the propriety:

$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1} $

Applying the propriety we have:

$ T(n) = nc(\frac{(3/2)^{lgn} - 1}{(3/2) - 1}) + \theta(n^{lg3}) \\ 
  T(n) = nc(3^{lgn} - 2) + \theta(n^{lg3}) \\
  T(n) = \theta(n^{lg3}) $